# How to add a custom html attribute to a field on view in openerp (odoo) v8?

Tags: field, odoo, record, qwebview

I want to add a custom html attribute (say - download ) to a field (named - attachment) in the view 
I tried these

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <page string="Other Information" position="after">
    <page string="Questionnaire">
      <label string="Questions &amp; Answers" for="answers"/>
      <field name="answers">
       <tree string="Questions &amp; Answers Lines" editable="bottom">
         <field name="order_id" invisible="True"  />
         <field name="line_id" domain="[('order_id', '=', order_id)]" required="True" />
         <field name="item_no" required="True" />
         <field name="question_id" required="True" />
         <field name="answer_id" domain="[('question_id', '=', question_id)]"  required="True" />
         <field name="priority_no" />
         <field name="attachment_alt" invisible="True" />
         <field name="attachment"  attrs="{'invisible':[('attachment_alt', '=', 'None')]}" filename="answer_id" download="answer_id" class="download-binary" />
         <!-- The above attachment field need the download attribute -->
      </tree>
      </field>
    </page>
  </page>
</field>
```

The field attachment was a binary field which contains png image data. How can achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you describe your fields in a form view, try to put your architecture between sheet tag like this

```
<sheet>
     <field name="field_name" download="something" />
     ....
</sheet>
```